# Different databases for different environments in DataAccesLayer DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have 4 layers in my project:

```
Business, DataAccess, Entities, UI
```

And this project runs on a real server. Now I want my development environment not effecting my real application. I mean, If I want to test something this shouldn't be changing in my server. So I need to separate my environments.

Actually for `AddDbContext - ApplicationIdentityDbContext` I did that correctly in start-up, but my real `DbContext` is in my `DataAccess` layer which is a different project in the same solution.

I've already tried: 
https://medium.com/danielpadua/efcore-implementing-a-multi-environment-designtimedbcontextfactory-399f243a9dda

but in this approach where there is a class called `ApplicationContextDesignFactory` takes a `typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name)`.

Because of a reference problem I can't call `Startup.cs` from my UI Layer into my DataAccess layer. Has anyone got an idea for this ?

By the way my `DbContext` had a configuring method

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=!ServerName!; Database=DbName; User Id=****; Password=******; ");
}
```

but the classes I implemented from the link above needed to implement also

```
public PortalContext(DbContextOptions<PortalContext> options) : base(options)
{
}
```

because those classes are take the connection strings from `appsettings.{environmentName}.json`.

Comment: Reference [Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I'm sure that this is not the best practice, but at least that is a solution.

I changed my DbContext which is in DataAccessLayer to:

```
public PIAppContext(DbContextOptions<PIAppContext> options) 
        : base(options)
{

}
```

and I've transported the factory classes to a folder created in WebUI layer.
(reference link : https://medium.com/danielpadua/efcore-implementing-a-multi-environment-designtimedbcontextfactory-399f243a9dda)

I have two same connection strings defined in `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.Development.json`:

In `appsettings.json` my connection string is :

```
"BlogConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Database=BlogDbProduction; integrated security=true;"
```

and in `appsettings.Development.json` my connection string is:

```
"BlogConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Database=BlogDbDevelopment; integrated security=true;"
```

and I added the DbContext in `Startup.cs` as a service:

```
services.AddDbContext<PIAppContext>(opts =>
       opts.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("BlogConnection")));
```

And I have created a simple app where you can easily create a new blog to a database.

So how can we change the environments?

Right click to your startup project which is my UI layer, go to properties and in Debug Section-> IIS  you can change the environment from development to production.

While you select **Development** and add a new blog to the database it will go to your `appsettings.Development.json`'s connection string and if you change it to **Production** then it will go to your `appsettings.json`'s connection string.

**MIGRATIONS**

If you want to migrate to your Development Database then you should go to **Nuget Package Manager Console** and set the environment to Development ( $env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Development") and add migration -> database update

If you want to migrate to your Production Database then you should do the same steps but set your environment to "**Production**"

**PUBLISH**

Now we have 2 different environments.
We can complete our testing process by setting the environment as Development as its defined in Debug itself, and when you publish your project you have to set your environment to Production in web.config, so your real projects which is published wont use your Development Database, it will use your Production Database.

**NOTE**: this is not a good solution, this is how I figured out how to separate environments.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string in your context factory should be your development connection string. As the name of the interface indicates, this is for *design time*, i.e. development. You should not be running migrations directly against your production database. Instead, you should be generating SQL scripts, a dacpac, or using a tool specifically for this like those from Red Gate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I dont know how to use those tools or generate those scripts, so I tried something else, below you can see my solution for this. I know thats not a "real" solution but please give a comment on it. I wonder your answer.. :)

Comment: Because as you said, the environment will always remain Development till you manually change it, and when you published it will automatically set the environment(also your connection) to your production environment.